# What do Engineers breathe?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

While entering the atmosphere of LV-226, the captain is informed that the moon's atmosphere is comprised of 3/4 hydrogen and the remaining is oxygen. So a human can't breath for more than 2 minutes.

Also while entering the temple of Engineers, Dr. Halloway say that the sun is heating up the water making the air breathable for humans.

*If engineers are the ancestors of humans, we can assume that they might have breathed oxygen.*

**Question 1**: In that case, how did they survived on that moon if they breathe oxygen?

**Question 2**: If they didn't breathe oxygen, how did they survive inside the temple?

Comment: "If engineers are the ancestors of humans, we can assume that they might have breathed oxygen" - we cannot assume that, as all we know is they 'seeded' earth with their own DNA.  The entire evolutionary process after that may have adapted the resulting species to the local atmosphere.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/was-the-atmosphere-on-lv-223-3-carbon-dioxide-or-monoxide?rq=1

Comment: The moon wasn't their home planet, just a base they were using, so I don't see why they couldn't have survived the same way as the humans in the movie: by having a breathable atmosphere in the temples and ships, and wearing environmental suits (like the elephant-looking helmet) when they went outside.

Comment: 3/4 Hydrogen, 1/4 Oxygen - no smoking! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SLsFAAHVZs

Comment: Coffee. Oh - you mean in the movie.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've mishead; it's not hydrogen, it's *nitrogen* that is dominant in the atmosphere, which means that the nitrogren and oxygen components are quite similar to Earth ([78.09% nitrogen, 20.95% oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth)).

The stated reason in the movie for why humans can't breathe is the high carbon dioxide content, which at over 3% is significantly higher than that of Earth (0.039%, so it's almost 100 times higher):

> Janek: What is the atmosphere?
>
> Ravel: Atmosphere is 71 percent nitrogen, 21 percent oxygen, traces of argon gas.
>
> Janek: Whoa, now, that's weather.
>
> Charlie Holloway: Just like home.
>
> Ford: Only if you're breathing through an exhaust pipe. CO2 is over 3 percent. Two minutes without a suit, you're dead.

The Engineers obviously therefore breathe a similar nitrogen/oxygen mix to that which we do, but have higher tolerance for carbon dioxide.

On an interesting sidenote, and as noted [in this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24878/8719), carbon *dioxide* in the movie is an obvious error: carbon dioxide in that concentration is not so poisonous, and nor is it in any event produced by an exhaust; carbon *monoxide* is what it obviously should be.

That the Engineers might have a biological requirement for breathing such a high level of carbon monoxide (or dioxide) may be discounted.  The atmosphere inside their ship was breathable by humans (as the scene in the control room - where the humans are without their helmets - confirms), so evidently their preferred atmosphere mix is something that is breathable by humans, i.e non-lethal to us.  However, the surviving Engineer apparently made it from his ship to the lifeboat without a helmet, so they appear to have a higher tolerance for a mixture that would be fatal to humans.

Comment: Why can't we consider a requirement for high CO2?  They may have a hybrid repository system which works both like an animals and like a plants...  This is scifi, anything can happen.

Comment: @Moo - because the movie establishes that their DNA is identical to ours.

Comment: I'd love a citation on that, because as I remember it there was a link between the DNA, but it was never said it was completely identical.

Comment: And anyhow, there are enough other differences between the Engineers and humans physically (height, strength, build etc etc) that even with "identical DNA" there could be others, such as a difference in respiratory systems.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the Engineers "have a higher tolerance for carbon dioxide" than we do, or is this just speculation? There is no evidence that they walked around on the surface without helmets on, is there?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - IIRC the Engineer got from the crashed ship to the lifeboat without a helmet.  It's equally possible of course that he was just able to hold his breath for long enough.

Comment: @Darth Satan - good point, although as you say it's possible he was just holding his breath, or that he was able to get from the ship to the lifeboat in less than the "two minutes" that Ford said would kill a human (or that they just had a higher tolerance in the sense of being able to last a bit longer without dying, not in the sense of being fine with breathing that amount for long periods).

Comment: @Hypnosifl its worth noting in the scene in the life boat, the interior of the life boat is exposed to the exterior atmosphere for the entire duration of the Engineers confrontation of Shaw (he busts in through the airlock), the subsequent fight with the alien, the implantation and Shaws escape.  Shaw is wearing her full suit including helmet during this scene.  Later on, the Engineer is seen waking up after the implantation, none the worse for wear for being exposed to the high CO2 atmosphere for the duration.  Of course the alien may have assisted in his breathing, but thats speculation...

Comment: ... based on earlier films (where Kane is implanted in the first film on LV-426, he survives the entire trip back to the ship while being exposed to the atmosphere the other EVA members cannot breathe.  In the scene from Prometheus mentioned above, there is significant exertion on the part of the Engineer in the attempt to get into the life boat, and the subsequent fight with the alien, and yet he never seems to be troubled by the atmosphere.

Comment: @Moo you may be right about the alien embryo altering the Engineer's physiology in order to survive, I seem to remember it's stated in one of the Alien films that the embryo can genetically alter the host somewhat in order to increase the chances of the fetus surviving the incubation period.

Comment: Slight nitpick: it's carbon _monoxide_. Carbon dioxide at 3% is perfecty tolerable (monoxide is lethal within few minutes). Well, _almost perfectly_ tolerable, it wouldn't be very comfortable to breate since you would somewhat hyperventilate... but it's not lethal within minutes. The movie script writer got that one wrong.

Comment: @Damon - true, yes.  I should update the answer to reflect a lot of the discussion going on in these comments...

Comment: @Moo - added some updates; you're forgetting the control room scene where humans and an Engineer were both present, without helmets, in the same atmosphere.

Comment: @DarthSatan I'm not forgetting that at all - go check out the mixtures in our space ships today :)  They don't 100% reflect native atmospheres but stay within the tolerance range we can live with.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the principle outputs from fire are CO2 and Water, and that includes automobiles. The reason CO is such a big deal is not due to how much is created, which isn't all that much, but because it is poisonous. CO reacts with red blood cells the same way that O2 does, so it prevent the red cells from absorbing enough O2.